# Using WebAPI Route attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a few methods, which I want to follow a specific pattern for their URLs.

Basically there's restaurants, which have IDs, and a collection of Terminals under them.

I'm trying to get the following sort of pattern to emerge:
api/Restaurant - get all Restaurants
api/Restaurant/Bobs - gets the restaurant with the ID of Bobs
api/Restaurant/Bobs/terminals - get all terminals in bobs restaurant
api/Restaurant/bobs/terminals/second - get the terminal with the ID of second in the restaurant bob

I've got the methods to do this, and I've assigned the Route attribute to each as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<IRestaurant> Get()
    {
        //do stuff, return all
    }

    [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Restaurant/{restuarantName}")]
        public IRestaurant Get(string restaurantName)
        {
           //do stuff
        }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/restuarant/{restaurantName}/terminals")]
    public IEnumerable<IMiseTerminalDevice> GetDevices(string restaurantName)
    {
       //do stuff
    } 

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/restaurant/{restaurantName}/terminals/{terminalName}")]
    public IMiseTerminalDevice GetDeviceByName(string restaurantName, string terminalName)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

However only my basic GET (api/Restaurant) is working.  My WebAPI config is the default, and reads

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Anybody know where I'm going wrong?  All other methods return routing mismatch (restaurant with ID) or a 404.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you mean by `and reads config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`?...are you calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` because this is the one which probes controllers and registers attribute routes in the route table...also note that requests matching conventional routing will never match controllers/actions decorated with attribute routes..

Comment: @Mathieson Could you please add post your request ? I have tried your APIs with the default template and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, that section is the value of the WebApiConfig class - fixed formatting to make it clearer.

Comment: @Toan - sure!

The url http://localhost:4675/api/restaurant/ returns the proper JSON.

The url http://localhost:4675/api/restaurant/bob fires the controller constructor, and returns "{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:4675/api/restaurant/bob'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Restaurant' that matches the request."}"

The url http://localhost:4675/api/restaurant/bob/terminals just returns 404, and does not fire the controller constructor.

Comment: Maybe the "restuarant" typo doesn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have just created the default WEB API project which includes a ProductsController. Next, I pasted your api methods in.

```
  public class ProductsController:ApiController
    {



        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Restaurant/{restaurantName}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string restaurantName)
        {
            //do stuff
            return Ok("api/Restaurant/{restuarantName}");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/restuarant/{restaurantName}/terminals")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetDevices(string restaurantName)
        {
            //do stuff
            return Ok("api/restuarant/{restaurantName}/terminals");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/restaurant/{restaurantName}/terminals/{terminalName}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetDeviceByName(string restaurantName, string terminalName)
        {
            //do stuff
            return Ok("api/restaurant/{restaurantName}/terminals/{terminalName}");
        }
    }
```

Finally, I used Fiddler to make an request

```
**http://localhost:9969/api/restuarant/Vanbeo/terminals**
```

and everything works fine!

System Configs: Visual Studio 2013, WEB API 2.2, Net 4.5

Could you please retry with an empty project?

PS: I have to post this as an answer because there is not enough space in the comment!

Comment: I created a new WebAPI project, and replaced the ValuesController method with the code above - now I find that
        http://localhost:3322/API/restaurant/bob
returns correctly.

However
        http://localhost:3322/API/restaurant/bob/terminals
returns a 404

Comment: Can you just upgrade your Web API package to version 2.2 and retry again?

Comment: WebAPI is at 2.2.

I think there's a problem with the method names - changing my signature to 

[Route("api/restaurants/{restaurantName}/{terminalName}")]                     [Route("api/restaurants/{restaurantName}/terminals/{terminalName}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetTerminalByName(string restaurantName, string terminalName)

has enabled me to get to the method at least.  I've refactored to move to a larger aggregate root of Restaurant, so this can be a good way to sidestep the issue.  Still frustrating though - even the RouteDebugger isn't showing much!