# Web API and Attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, token

I am new in web api and attribute routing. just read a article from here. http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/a2bf5c05-18a6-44b3-9f73-5896b40f0dff.aspx

### see their attribute routing for web api action

```
[Route("api/[controller]/Logout")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return new ObjectResult("Success");
}
```

I have very basic questions.
this attribute routing is ok `[Route("api/[controller]/Logout")]` controller name should be wrapped in **{} or [ ]** ?

Is it mandatory that when work with token then we need to work with identity?

can't we generate token if we work with form authentication ?

I am very beginner developer. so please help me with knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111156/using-webapi-route-attribute

Comment: before {} is used for template now i saw [] is using as template see old code `[Route("api/restuarant/{restaurantName}/terminals")]` my posted code is related to .net core ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For convenience, attribute routes support token replacement by enclosing a token in square-braces ([, ]). The tokens [action], [area], and [controller] will be replaced with the values of the action name, area name, and controller name from the action where the route is defined.

The `[controller]` token is replaced with the name of the controller where the action is defined in.

See [Token replacement in route templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) to learn more about that.